# How to change matrix values to values from another matrix - Wolfram

Tags: list, dictionary, matrix, wolfram-mathematica, populate

I have just started my journey with Wolfram Mathematica and I want to implement a simple genetic algorithm. The construction of the data is given and I have to start with such rows/columns.

Here is what I have:

```
  chromosome := RandomSample[CharacterRange["A", "G"], 7]
    chromosomeList = Table[chromosome, 7] // MatrixForm
```

This gives me a matrix, where every row represents a chromosome:

[image]

```
yPos = Flatten[Position[chromosomeList, #], 1] & /@ {"A", "B", "C", 
    "D", "E", "F", "G"};
yPos = yPos[[All, 3 ;; 21 ;; 3]] // Transpose
```

Now every column represents a letter (From A to G) and every row it's index in every chromosome:

[image]

Here is a given efficiency matrix, where very row represents different letter (From A to G) and every column gives the value that should be applied on the particular position:

```
    efficiencyMatrix = {
  {34, 31, 20, 27, 24, 24, 18},
  {14, 14, 22, 34, 26, 19, 22},
  {22, 16, 21, 27, 35, 25, 30},
  {17, 21, 24, 16, 31, 22, 20},
  {17, 29, 22, 31, 18, 19, 26},
  {26, 29, 37, 34, 37, 20, 21},
  {30, 28, 37, 28, 29, 23, 19}}
```

[image]

What I want to do is to create a matrix with values that correspond to the letter and it's position. I have done it like that:

```
    values = Transpose[{ efficiencyMatrix[[1, yPos[[1]]]], 
   efficiencyMatrix[[2, yPos[[2]]]], 
   efficiencyMatrix[[3, yPos[[3]]]], 
   efficiencyMatrix[[4, yPos[[4]]]], 
   efficiencyMatrix[[5, yPos[[5]]]], 
   efficiencyMatrix[[6, yPos[[6]]]], 
   efficiencyMatrix[[7, yPos[[7]]]]}]
```

How can I write it in more elegant way?

Comment: You might want to ask this question at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com, but if you do delete it from this site.  Cross-posting is rather frowned upon.

Comment: a bit of a side note but it is usually not recommended to store anything in formatted form.  You should do `(chromosomeList = Table[chromosome, 7]) // MatrixForm` which stores the table and only formats for display.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a list of functions to some variable using the function `Through`, which is helpful when applying `Position` multiple times.  Because `Position[patt][expr] == Position[expr, patt]`, we can do

```
Through[ (Position /@ CharacterRange["A","C"])[{"B", "C", "A"}] ]
```

to get `{3, 1, 2}`.

`Position` can also operate on lists, so we can simplify finding `ypos` by doing

```
Transpose@Map[Last, Through[(Position /@ characters)[chromosomeList]], {2}]
```

where `characters` is the relevant output of `CharacterRange`.

We can also simplify dealing with ranges of integers by mapping over the `Range` function, so in total we end up with

```
characters   = CharacterRange["A","G"]
efficiencies = ...
chromosomes  = ...

ypos = Transpose@Map[Last, Through[(Position /@ characters)[chromosomes]], {2}];
efficiencies[[#, ypos[[#]]]]& /@ Range[Length[characters]] //Transpose ]
```